# About partial derivative and differentiability

Tags: calculus, analysis

Suppose that I was given such function $f:R^2→R$ with all its partial derivative $f_x, f_y$ defined in some neighborhood of a given point $(x_0,y_0)$, also I was given that $f_x, f_y$ are continuous at such point. **Does it implies that $f$ is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$?**
Particularly note that I was only given the continuity at $(x_0, y_0)$ and not necessarily for some neighborhood. It is easy to show that if so, then $f$ would be differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: The answer is "yes". There was a question about this topic recently: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2693086/why-are-continuous-partial-derivatives-a-sufficient-condition-for-differentiabil/2693145#2693145 . If you examine the proof carefully, you'll see that we require the existence of the partial derivatives in the neighbourhood, but we only require the continuity of the partial derivatives at the single point.