# Existence of directional derivative

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

For a two variable function, does the existence of continuous partial derivatives of order 1 with respect to $x$ and $y$ at a point $(x,y)$ imply the existence of the directional derivative in any direction at the point $(x,y)$?

Comment: Hint: Try defining the derivative with respect to an arbitrary direction, then separate it so it can be derived from the partial derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because:

1. The continuity of the partial derivatives implies that the function is differentiable at $(x,y)$. (This is a standard multi-variable calculus theorem.)
2. When a function is differentiable, it has directional derivatives in any direction.

Comment: Is it because the increment theorem is valid if the partial derivatives are continuous?

Comment: No. It's a conseuence of the mean value theorem.

Comment: Could u explain how?

Comment: It's too long for a comment, but you will find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2693086/446262).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer , the increment theorem is basically the same fact and it's proof is exactly the same proof u told me to check out . It basically states that change in  f = fy*change in y + fx * change in x + epsilon1*change in x + epsilon 2 * change in y where epsilon 1 and epsilon 2 tend to 0 as change in x and change in y tend to 0